# Toggle Feature?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So i'm attempting to make my bot toggle on and off whether or not to send messages in all caps or not. My problem is that when I try to change the variable value it doesn't change. Could anyone help me? New to both stack overflow and programming(ish, know enough to get me this far)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you add the relevant code you have so far to the question? If you have a string that you want to convert to uppercase (caps), you can call the string's [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)-method.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the [help] pages, take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Also please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: May you please provide some code?

Comment: I attempted to add code but failed in doing so, i just sorta gave up on trying to show the code and hoped someone would know what i was talking about

Comment: @NeedsHelp it sounds like you already got a basic bot working and sending basic messages, is that correct? What errors are you hitting? What have you tried so far? Please show us some code you attempted using so we can help point out errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use the [toUpperCase() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) (or the [toLowerCase() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp)) to make our string go all lower case or all upper case. for example:

```
let string = "example"
let toggledString = string.toUpperCase()
```

then later on we can have an `if` statement:

```
if (command == toggled) {
    message.channel.send(toggledString)
} else {
    message.channel.send(string)
}
```

the toggled string would output `EXAMPLE` while the other will output `example`

As for why your variables aren't being reassigned you're probably declaring them using `const` which does not allow the variable to be changed. You can just change `const` to `let` or `var` to fix this.